# Pink Screen on GRUB Boot

Tags: 11.04, boot, command-line, log, tty

When I boot Ubuntu 11.04, GRUB shows me a nice, blank pink screen, until most of the OS is loaded, after which I can see some output text.

I can't fix it unless I switch to console mode instead of graphics mode, but I don't want to do that because then I can't change the screen resolution.

**This used to work correctly in version 10.04 and 10.10.**

(I've even tried the `debug --verbose` boot option, but it only displays things on shutdown, not boot. Removing `quiet` or `splash` options doesn't help.)

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: You should be happy that you get a pink screen and not a [black screen of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Screen_of_Death) or a [blue screen of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death).

Comment: @N.N.: Actually, I get a blue screen if I install KDE. :P

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Terminal resolution is independent on guest additions. Virtual Box uses a standard terminal resolution for booting that can only be increased at a later stage.

However if you need to have a larger command line display you could try *Scale Mode* <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or *Full Screen Mode* <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for scaling the display windows size.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this pink screen of death (PSoD) doesn't happen to me on the older kernel

**Linux xxx 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux**

kernels 2.6.38-10 and -11 are causing that to me.

Comment: It depends on the settings; I've had both black and pink. When I use the old kernel in VirtualBox, the screen is still pure black -- no output until most things have booted.